# Python Randomly assign a list from a set number

Tags: python, list, random

What i'm trying to do is make a list that gets filled with different combinations of numbers (not even) that all add up to a pre defined number.

Example, if I have the a variable `total = 50` as well as a list that holds 7 numbers, each time I generate and print the list in a loop, the results will be completly different with some being huge and others near empty or empty.  I dont want any restrictions for the range of the value (could come as 0 or the entire 50, and next time may even be all balanced).

Is this possible?

Thanks

EDIT: I've gotten to here, but it seems to prioritize the ending, how can I make each variable have an equal chance of high or low numbers?

```
`import random
tot = 50
size = 7
s = 0
run = 7
num = {}
while run > 0:
    num[run] = random.randint(s,tot)
    tot -= num[run]
    run -= 1
print(str(num))
`
```

Comment: Please provide sample input, sample output, and what code you have tried so far. As it stands this question is unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't mind what this code is meant to be.

```
from random import randint, seed
seed(345)

def bizarre(total, slots):
    tot = total
    acc = []
    for _ in range(slots-1):
        r = randint(0,tot)
        tot -= r
        acc.append(r)
    acc.append(total-sum(acc))
    return acc

# testing code

for i in range(10):
    tot = randint(50,80)
    n   = randint(5,10)
    b = bizarre(tot, n)
    print "%3d %3d  %s -> %d" % (tot, n, b, sum(b))
```

#### *Output*

```
 73   5  [73, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 73
 54   6  [36, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1] -> 54
 60   7  [47, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0] -> 60
 69   7  [3, 48, 15, 3, 0, 0, 0] -> 69
 72   8  [36, 18, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 72
 65   8  [17, 32, 13, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 65
 54   7  [33, 13, 0, 2, 4, 1, 1] -> 54
 54   6  [7, 11, 26, 3, 5, 2] -> 54
 67   7  [62, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 67
 67   8  [28, 25, 1, 0, 10, 3, 0, 0] -> 67
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of n random numbers that add up to a variable x, create n-1 random numbers. Then last number is the difference between x and the n-1 random numbers. For example, if you want a list of size three that adds up to 5 create two numbers randomly, 1 and 2. 1+2 = 3, 5-3 = 2, so the list is 1,2,2.

Comment: I like how that sounds, but wouldn't that also give priority to the first couple of numbers and the last few would have a greater chance of being of lower value?